# MongoDB vs. Elasticsearch filtering

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have data in MongoDB and synced data in ElasticSearch. My requirement is to filter data based on certain parameters.

Let's say I am filtering data based on couple of parameters and retrieving a couple of hundred results from 10,000 documents.(I am mentioning numbers for perspective.)

Since this query is based on filtering and not search, which of the two perform better? MongoDB or ElasticSearch?
Intuitively it feels that ElasticSearch is fast and returns data quickly.

Given this scenario and indexed values in DB, is Mongo competitive with ElasticSearch? Should I even consider ElasticSearch at this scale?

Answer (score 1):

**Elasticsearch** is the right choice for the your requirement. It has two different concept query and filter

Please find below link for more explanation

http://blog.quarkslab.com/mongodb-vs-elasticsearch-the-quest-of-the-holy-performances.html